# Eigenvalues for $3\times 3$ stochastic matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stochastic-matrices

This is a plot of the non-real eigenvalues of $10^4$ randomly 
generated $3\times3$ stochastic matrices. It's pretty clear
that they lie in the convex hull of the three cube roots of unity.

[image]

The boundary on the left hand side is easy to explain. If the 
stochastic matrix $P$ has a non-real eigenvalue $\lambda$, then 
$\text{trace}(P)=\lambda+\bar\lambda+1=2\text{Re}(\lambda)+1$.
On the other hand, the trace of $P$ is 
also the sum of its diagonal entries, and hence 
is non-negative real number. Therefore, $\text{Re}(\lambda)\geq -{1\over 2}$.

I hope that there is an easy explanation for the other 2 sides of 
the triangle, perhaps in terms of some other matrix invariant. 
So far, I can't think of any. Any ideas?

By the way, it is not hard to show that every point in 
the triangle can be achieved as the eigenvalue of 
a stochastic matrix of the form
$$P=\begin{bmatrix}1-s-t&s&t\\ t&1-s-t&s\\ s&t&1-s-t \end{bmatrix}$$
for some $s\geq 0, t\geq 0, s+t\leq 1$.

Comment: So the claim is $1 + \lambda x + \bar{\lambda} x^2 \geq 0$ where $x$ is the cube-root of unity and you want to view it as some matrix invariant?

Comment: Spoiler: [On $p$'th roots of stochastic matrices](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~higham/papers/hili11.pdf)

Comment: Can you prove there's a stochastic matrix with $\alpha$ as an eigenvalue if and only if there's one with $e^{2\pi i/3}\alpha$ as an eigenvalue?

Comment: @Marvis Yes, this or any other simple proof.

Comment: @Emre Thanks for the reference. At least I know that the result is true. I would still like a simple proof for the $n=3$ case.

Comment: @GerryMyerson This is what I was unable to prove.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The invariant that I was looking for is $3(\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2)-(\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3)^2$, which is non-negative for any non-negative $3\times 3$ matrix $P$. When the eigenvalues are $1$, $\lambda$, and $\bar\lambda$, this means that 
$$3(1+2\,\text{Re}(\lambda^2))\geq (1+2\,\text{Re}(\lambda))^2,$$
which can be rewritten as 
$$(1-\text{Re}(\lambda))^2\geq 3\,\text{Im}(\lambda)^2.$$
This gives the other two sides of the triangle in the plot.

---

Here is a proof of the claim above. Using the positivity of $P$ and the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\lambda_1^2+\lambda_2^2+\lambda_3^2&=&\text{Trace}(P^2)\\
&=&\left(\sum_j p_{1j}p_{j1}\right)+\left(\sum_j p_{2j}p_{j2}\right)+\left(\sum_j p_{3j}p_{j3}\right)\\
&\geq&p_{11}^2+p_{22}^2+p_{33}^2\\
&\geq&{1\over 3}\left(p_{11}+p_{22}+p_{33}\right)^2\\
&=&{1\over 3}\left(\lambda_{1}+\lambda_{2}+\lambda_{3}\right)^2\\
\end{eqnarray*}

**Reference.** R. Loewy and D. London, *A note on an inverse problem for non-negative matrices*, Linear and Multilinear Algebra, **Volume 6**, pages 83-90, 1978.

Comment: "...which is non-negative for any non-negative..." mmm some hint?

Comment: @leonbloy I've added more information on this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The question by the OP omits one detail that might be misleading: If $\Theta_n$ denotes the subset of the complex plane that contains all eigenvalues of every $n$-by-$n$ stochastic matrix, then $\Theta_n \subseteq \Theta_{n+1}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ because, if $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ stochastic matrix, then
$$ \begin{bmatrix}
A & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
is an $(n+1)$-by-$(n+1)$ stochastic matrix.

It is also known and easy to show that $\Theta_2 = [-1,1]$ given that the eigenvalues of the two-by-two *circulant* matrix
$$\frac{1}{2}\begin{bmatrix}
\lambda + \mu & \lambda - \mu \\
\lambda - \mu & \lambda + \mu
\end{bmatrix}$$ are $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

If $\omega_n := \exp(2\pi i /n)$, then $\Theta_3 = \text{conv}(1,\omega_2)\cup \text{conv}(1,\omega_3,\omega_3^2)$.