# real spectrum of an almost symmetric stochastic matrix

Tags: matrices, spectral-theory

Let $M$ be a real nonnegative square matrix ''almost'' symmetric ($A_{ij}=0$ if and only if $A_{ji}=0$). In addition, $M$ is irreducible (not necessarily primitive) and row stochastic (the sum of each row is 1). I wish to prove that all the eigenvalues of $M$ are real. Do you think this is true?

Comment: Nonnegative means all coefficients are nonnegative I guess?

Answer (score 3):

No. The eigenvalues of $
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1/2 & 1/3 & 1/6 \\
        1/6 & 1/2 & 1/3 \\
        1/3 & 1/6 & 1/2 \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
 are $1,\  1/4+i\sqrt{3}/12,\ \text{and } 1/4-i\sqrt{3}/12.$

Comment: I was looking for a $2\times 2$ counterexample...to finally come to the conclusion that the fact is true in this case. So your counterexample is the best possible, +1.

Comment: The eigenvalues for $2\times 2$ stochastic matrices are both real. I had explored the $3\times 3$ case earlier here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141212/eigenvalues-for-3-times-3-stochastic-matrices

Comment: Yes, I figured this out when looking for a counterexample. Thanks for the link.

Comment: No problem. Thanks for the upvotes!

Comment: You're most welcome: it is always a pleasure to upvote nice answers/questions.