# Generating a stochastic matrix with a given second dominant eigenvalue

Tags: linear-algebra, algorithms, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, spectral-graph-theory

I need a procedure (iterative or otherwise) that, given a positive integer $N$ and a (possibly complex) number $\lambda$ such that $0 < \vert \lambda \vert < 1$, will be able to generate an $N \times N$ stochastic matrix $\mathbf{M}$ (in which every column sums to $1$) whose second-largest (in absolute value) eigenvalue is $\lambda$. The constraint is only on $\vert \lambda \vert$ and it does not matter if $\lambda$ is complex.

The first (largest-magnitude) eigenvalue is always $1$. The rest of the eigenvalues are arbitrary.

I need the procedure (if one exists) to always converge with a correct answer with probability $1$ (if it is iterative).

I need this in Markov chain simulations and I want to control the convergence rate from the initial distributions to the equilibrium one.

**EDIT**: It is also important to know that randomly generating a stochastic matrix in Matlab (shown in the figure below) yields a relatively small second-largest eigenvalue, indicating that the probability of having large second-largest eigenvalue is small and it needs to be crafted. You can also see the eigenvalue $1$ that always exists in isolation on the far right. The figure below is the spectra of $10000$ randomly generated $16 \times 16$ stochastic matrices.
[image]

As pointed out in the comments, I found a [paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379584900181#) that constructs a doubly stochastic matrix explicitly from a given positive spectrum. However, the constructed matrices are, in fact, very concentrated around the diagonal (these can be called *lazy Markov chains* since they tend to stay where they are). This result explains why it is extremely unlikely that a randomly generated stochastic matrix would have eigenvalues closer to $1$ than shown in the above figure. This means there is only local transitions between Markov chain states with very weak global transitions. **Is that indeed implied by asking for large eigenvalues of the transition matrix**?

Here is a surface plot of a $100 \times 100$ stochastic matrix constructed from a randomly generated positive spectrum as explained in [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379584900181#).

[image]

I also found a result [here](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/~pw/M100W11/nathan.pdf) saying that lazy, reversible Markov chains have positive spectra, which is in line with the above result.

Comment: For fixed $N$, the eigenvalues of all stochastic matrices do not fill up the unit ball so this will not be possible for every $\lambda$. For the $3\times 3$ case, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141212/eigenvalues-for-3-times-3-stochastic-matrices

Comment: Thanks Mr. Byron for the very informative post. In your question, the point $1$ is still not an isolated eigenvalue, so real eigenvalues can be used. I indeed found a paper (http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0024379584900181#) that explicitly constructs a doubly stochastic matrix having a prescribed positive spectrum. So at least the real axis between $0$ and $1$ is covered.

Comment: What if you take your "lazy" doubly stochastic matrix $M$ (with arbitrary positive spectrum) and look at $S^{-1} M S$ where $S$ is a random stochastic matrix? The result should still be stochastic matrix and it should have the same spectrum as $M$ but "look more random".